# MySQL - Slow performance for limit offset on json column

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm seeing slow performance when using a LIMIT OFFSET on a SELECT statement for a table that includes a JSON column.

The following query takes 3 minutes to complete:

```
SELECT t.json_column
FROM table t
LIMIT 501
OFFSET 216204;
```

However, if I only select `t.id`, the query only takes a couple of milliseconds.

The slow performance is only visible when the JSON column is part of the SELECT statement, but I don't understand why, or what can I do to improve it.

To give more context, the MySql version I'm using is 5.7, the service is running on an AWS Aurora database, and the number of rows on the table is ~216.000

Comment: if you aren't supplying an order by, there's no guarantee what order your results will be in, or that it will be the same between two queries, so your limit and offset are meaningless.  can you provide an example closer to what you are actually doing?

Comment: Please include the execution plan of both queries.

Comment: Without being able to compare the execution plans this discussion is fruitless. Voting to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler - If you have seen one `EXPLAIN` with `LIMIT`, you have seen them all.  And you will know that the `EXPLAIN` is mostly useless.

Comment: Did someone actually step through about 400 rows to get to this query?  Please explain how you got that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When MySQL uses `OFFSET`, it cannot just skip to row 216204. MySQL indexes index by value, not by row number. So it must actually examine all those rows, which means reading the pages on which the rows are stored. Loading them from disk into RAM if necessary.

When you only reference `t.id`, it can scan along the index. I'll assume `id` is indexed (maybe even the primary key), and it's probably an integer (4 bytes) or bigint (8 bytes). Regardless, a lot of those entries can fit in a given InnoDB page (each page is of fixed size, 16KB each).

Whereas the JSON column is like TEXT or BLOB or VARCHAR, in that it is probably stored on additional pages, and it's much more bulky than a single integer. So it takes more pages. If the JSON documents are especially large, it may even take many pages per document.

So that's a lot of storage I/O to load all those JSON documents. It is many times the I/O work to load 216,000 JSON documents, compared to only referencing the primary key. It might be the case that the primary key pages are already cached in RAM anyway, so there is little or no I/O needed to read them.

It might be even worse with AWS Aurora than traditional MySQL, because Aurora uses distributed storage and replicated buffer pools, so there's additional overhead to both the I/O and the loading into RAM.

## What can you do instead?

Stop using large values in your `OFFSET`. Search by values instead.

```
SELECT t.json_column
FROM table t
WHERE t.id >= 208000
LIMIT 501;
```

This is quick because the index helps to skip directly to the 208,000th row *without* examining all the preceding rows. It will only need to examine the rows starting with the row where id=208000 (or whatever value you search for). It stops examining rows once it finds enough for your `LIMIT`.

Comment: this bothers me; does `SELECT json_column FROM table WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 501 OFFSET 216204)` outperform `SELECT json_column FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 501 OFFSET 216204`?  I really don't see why it would

Comment: That would only read `id` for the 216204 rows, so it would avoid reading that many JSON documents. Then the subquery would return at most 501 id's and that would cause the outer query to use the index to examine only 501 rows, with the respective JSON documents. It is usually quicker to do the I/O to load 501 JSON documents than 216204 JSON documents.

Comment: if `id` is the PK, then the main index is not tiny, but includes all the columns of the table.

Comment: @TheImpaler, not if the JSON is large enough. Long string or blob type data will overflow onto other pages.

Comment: what I'm missing is why it reads all the json documents for the rows it will be skipping.  would `SELECT json_column FROM table USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ...` avoid that?  or is it always going to read all of any select fields even for rows excluded by limit/offset?

Comment: It must read the columns in the select-list before it knows if the row satisfies the limit & offset.

Comment: That `SELECT` _assumes_ that no ids are missing below 20800.  There are _several_ ways for an auto_increment to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON column is large, correct?  If so, this *might* run faster:

```
SELECT t.json_column
    FROM ( SELECT id
        FROM table
        LIMIT 501
        OFFSET 216204 ) AS ids
    JOIN table AS t  USING(id);
```

The inner query might be able to grab the 501 ids fast enough to compensate for the `JOIN`.

(Still, see the other Answers and Comments.)