# Slow LIMIT Queries on MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Summary: I'm trying to export data from a large partitioned MySQL table, but the LIMIT queries are taking a long time.

Hi,  I have a large MySQL database (AWS Aurora 5.7). Total size about 5TB. One table is 2.5TB.
Here is the table structure

| column | type |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| partition | int(10) unsigned | primary key |
| user_id | binary(16) | primary key |
| group_id | binary(16) | primary key |
| hash | binary(16) | primary key |
| value | json |  |

For each day there is a new partition created. It is a range partition. There are about 700 partitions now.

I'm trying to export the entire table. Running queries 1 partition at a time using LIMIT queries like this:

```
SELECT HEX(`hash`), `value`
FROM my_table
WHERE partition=... AND user_id=... AND  group_id=...
LIMIT 200000, 100000
```

Such queries take a range of 1-3 minutes each. Once I get the result, I run the next query increasing the "LIMIT start index". The first query with "LIMIT 0" is faster. The bigger "LIMIT" is, the slower it takes.

For example if I query only 1000 rows, without any "WHERE" conditions, here are the results:

```
LIMIT       0, 1000 -> 0.000sec
LIMIT    1000, 1000 -> 0.015sec
LIMIT   10000, 1000 -> 0.094sec
LIMIT  100000, 1000 -> 0.400sec
LIMIT 1000000, 1000 -> 5.781sec
```

How do I make the queries faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large `OFFSET` values are a challenge for a database that indexes by value, not by row number or position. I answered a similar question here: [MySQL - Slow performance for limit offset on json column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267182/mysql-slow-performance-for-limit-offset-on-json-column/70267262#70267262)

However, the solution in that question won't work for you, because you haven't specified an order for the rows returned by your query. I can guess that the rows in your selected set have no meaningful order, because the only column of the PK you aren't filtering by is a hash.

I don't know what to suggest for you, except to increase the CPU and RAM of your database instance, to hopefully hold more data in RAM and make access faster.

Another possibility is to create a new column for subpartitioning, and use that instead of LIMIT and OFFSET.

There aren't any good logical fixes.

Comment: Bill, thanks a lot! This is pretty useful. Turns out all except one table have an integer ID column and Partition(numeric) columns. Should be able to use that and "WHERE id > prev_seen_id" instead of limit start value.

Comment: There is just one table with multiple binary columns (see the description). My queries are "WHERE partition = ... AND user_id = ... AND group_id = ...". Only the "hash" column is left unfiltered. In the results I see that it is always in order. Is it guaranteed to stay like that as long is it is part of the primary key? If yes, I would be able to filter by "hash > previous_largest_seen_hash" and iterate to the next page. Thank you!

Comment: It's not guaranteed. In practice, the rows are returned in the order they are read from the index. But since the index used might change because of the optimizer's choice, the safest thing to do in any query with `LIMIT` is to specify an `ORDER BY` clause to be explicit.

Comment: I agree with Bill Karwin. Even the same query can pick a different index to use when values in table condition change. For instance, what MySQL would normally use as a secondary index to perform an index lookup using range as its access type could be changed to full table scan as cardinality and selectivity drops in indexed columns. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, changes to what index MySQL chooses to use can change the order of the result set shown, based on the newly used index's sequence.

Comment: In my case all other indexes were queried, so the last one would be used to implement pagination. I noticed that the results were consistently ordered, but just for the sake of safety, I've added: "ORDER BY pagination_column". Thanks.